# TemplateSyntaxError, Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django-admin, django-templates

I'm following the django tutorial at Django by example in http://www.lightbird.net/.
In the first example, TodoList, Customizing Model Template part, I've copied the template to
todo/item.

```
{% block content %}
<a href="{% url admin:todo_datetime_add %}">Add Todo items</a>
```

Above is what I add in the change_list.html as the website content said.

I want to reuse the admin/change_list.html and add a link right after the block content line.
But when I visit the url, I get the TemplateSyntaxError:

```
Template error

In template /pathtomyworkspace/TodoList/TodoList/templates/admin/todo/item/change_list.html, error at line 58
Could not parse the remainder: ':todo_datetime_add' from 'admin:todo_datetime_add'
```

I just wonder what should I do to use the 'admin:' namespaces in the template.
Do I need to add something in the urls.py file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had to put quotes around the url.

changed: `admin:todo_datetime_add`

to: `'admin:todo_datetime_add'`

Comment: Did you find out why you need to put quotes around the url? Is it something new introduced into a newer version of django?

Comment: Can't say that I did. Just stumbled over it somewhere, and it worked for me.

Comment: It was introduced in [1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: this solved the problem for me too, but im on 1.4.  Furthermore, in some templates it works without the quotes but in others i need to use quotes.  What is going on here?